# Redirect after URL changes on $stateChangeStart event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have some logic on the `$stateChangeStart` event, to check if state with parameters (URL) is correct. If it is not I want to redirect it to the `404` view:

```
event.preventDefault();
$state.go('404');
```

But this solution is incorrect, because if you are moving between states, and `404` error occurs, it redirects to the `404` view, but URL is still of the working page, because it is a `$stateChangeStart` event (it didn't move to the state with a problem and it didn't change the URL). **It is probably because of the `event.preventDefault()`.**

I can't use `$stateChangeSuccess` event.

So what should I use instead of `event.preventDefault()` to achieve my goal?

Comment: If the state is configured with an url then the url should change right? Could you set up a plunker?

Comment: @RobsonGilli 404 state is without url, that means that the view changes but url stays the same

Comment: Right, and what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Sorry it's not clear to me...

Comment: Why don't use `$stateChangeError`? It should be fired when something goes wrong during the state change.

Comment: @RobsonGilli @pasine I don't have any errors initially, I figure out it only in the `$stateChangeStart` , I run some logic there to check state params, and if params `Not Found` I redirect to the `404` view. Problem is, that because of the `event.preventDefault()`, `404` page shows with the previous, working URL.

Comment: As far as I can see, since you didn't set up an url for that state, it will keep the url as it is, regadless of the event.preventDefault(), am i right?

Comment: @RobsonGilli yes, but `event.preventDefault()` don't let the URL to change from the correct (previous page) to incorrect (current page with 404 error)

Comment: I see, I think there's nothing wrong using preventDefault(), it's even in the documentation of the ui-router (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state), "'transition prevented' - when event.preventDefault() has been called in a $stateChangeStart listener"